# Can you use multiple values in a switch statement (C#)

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I know that using multiple values in a switch case should mean you ought to be using an if-else setup but this is more of a theory question than a practicality.

My question is thus:

```
switch(x){
    case 4:
        break;
    case 5 || 6:
        break;
}
```

The above `5 || 6` illustrates the case firing on either x being 5 or 6.

Is this at all possible?

Edit: This is a question as to the design of the `switch` decision making rather than using fall-throughs.

Comment: more like:
```
case 5:
case 6:
break;
```

Comment: [Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-switch-section)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, with help of `Pattern matching` in C#7
I know this not the elegant way, but its what OP asks for

```
switch(x){
    case var rule when x == 4:
        //do your things
        break;
    case var rule when x == 5 || x == 6:
        //do your other things
        break;
}
```

Comment: “of course you can” — except that, until very recently, you couldn’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, yeah your right, rest of sentence almost implied that :).

Answer (score 8):

You can just fall through like this to match 5 or 6:

```
switch(x){
    case 4:
        break;
    case 5:
    case 6:
        // do something for 5 or 6
        break;
}
```